# Очень странный цикл

Tags: php

Этот цикл должен выводить 1,2,3,4, но почему он выводит 2,3,4,5 ?

```
$a = 1;
while($a++ < 5 ){
    echo $a;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Измените свой код так:

```
$a = 1;

while($a < 5 ){

    echo $a++;

}
```

[Песочница](https://onlinephp.io/c/cd178).

Постфиксный инкремент внутри while сначала сравнивает вашу переменную c числом 5,и только потом прибавляет 1.

Comment: Чтобы добиться желаемого результата, нужно, чтобы счетчик с инкрементом был до объявления echo? Верно ли я понял вашу трактовку?

Comment: Мой код дает желаемый результат. Если вы инициализируете счетчик в 1 (переменную $a=1) то прибавлять единицу нужно после того как выведете ее при  помощи echo. Что и делает мой код